# Why "webdriver-manager start" works on and off?

Tags: protractor

I run the **webdriver-manager start** but now it is not working all the time. I try to run it with the `--proxy` option and sometimes it works and sometimes not.I also get the following error.

> Error:getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com: 443

But after 5 minutes I ran it and it worked well!
Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but probably issue was corresponding to port. When command was running first time from console you have wiped console but process was still alive. So you caught this error when was trying to run this command again from another console but previous process was still alive and was a root of error. Just try firstly end process and only then close a console.